# how do I change multiple divs ids/class so the styling changes?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/GHuwV/2/

```
$("#container").each(function () {

    $(this).find('.taskName').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Each') {
            $(this).css('div#gold div.gold', 'gold');
            $(this).find('.taskName').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Offer') {
                    $(this).css('div#red div.red', 'red');
                    $(this).find('.taskName').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).attr('value') == 'Buying') {
                            $(this).css('div#green div.green', 'green');
                        }
                    });

                });

<div id="container">
    <div id="goldpricebox1">
        <div id="goldpricebox2">
            <input id="coin" type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="width: 35px; style=" height: 21px; maxlength=3 />
            <div id="goldselectbox1">
                <div id="goldselectbox2">
                    <div id="goldselectbox3">
                        <select name="qty">
                            <option value="Each" selected>Each</option>
                            <option value="All"> All</option>
                            <option value="Offer">Offer</option>
                            <option value="Buying">Buying</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="goldpricebox3">
                <div id="goldpricebox4">
                    <div class="goldpricebox5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

input#coin {
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif, Geneva, Verdana;
    font-size:1em;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(http://kennenmen.netai.net/images/gcoin.png)
}
input {
    display: block;
    margin : 0 auto;
    height: 14px;
}
select {
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif, Geneva, Verdana;
    font-size:1em;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
select {
    display: block;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
/*GOLD*/
 div#goldpricebox1 {
    background: none;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #361801;
    float:left;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
div#goldpricebox2 {
    background-color: #EEC43A;
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
div#goldpricebox3 {
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
}
div#goldpricebox4 {
    border:1px solid #361801;
}
div.goldpricebox5 {
    border:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background: white;
    width: 153px;
    min-height: 51px;
    height: auto;
    padding-botttom:25px;
}
div#goldselectbox1 {
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
}
div#goldselectbox2 {
    border:1px solid #361801;
}
div#goldselectbox3 {
    border:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background: white;
}
/*GREEN*/
 div#greenpricebox1 {
    background: none;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #013601;
    float:left;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
div#greenpricebox2 {
    background-color: #39EE39;
    border:1px solid #83FF83;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
div#greenpricebox3 {
    border:1px solid #83FF83;
}
div#greenpricebox4 {
    border:1px solid #013601;
}
div.greenpricebox5 {
    border:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background: white;
    width: 153px;
    min-height: 51px;
    height: auto;
    padding-botttom:25px;
}
div#greenselectbox1 {
    border:1px solid #83FF82;
}
div#greenselectbox2 {
    border:1px solid #013601;
}
div#greenselectbox3 {
    border:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background: white;
}
/* Red */
 div#redpricebox1 {
    background: none;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #360101;
    float:left;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
div#redpricebox2 {
    background-color: #EE3939;
    border:1px solid #FF8383;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
div#redpricebox3 {
    border:1px solid #FF8383;
}
div#redpricebox4 {
    border:1px solid #360101;
}
div.redpricebox5 {
    border:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background: white;
    width: 153px;
    min-height: 51px;
    height: auto;
    padding-botttom:25px;
}
div#redselectbox1 {
    border:1px solid #FF8383;
}
div#redselectbox2 {
    border:1px solid #360101;
}
div#redselectbox3 {
    border:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background: white;
}
```

**What am I trying to do?**
I'm trying to change the div boxes colors depending on the select/option box.
All and Each should make the box gold
Buying should make the box green
Offer should make the box red

**What have I tried?**
Being new to coding I haven't tried everything I've tried changing the jquery around with no results.

**What must i keep?**
Its vital I keep all the styling in the .css and keep the current .class and #ids for all the the divs.

**What the Boxes should look like**
http://jsfiddle.net/GHuwV/4/

Thanking anyone who can help me out as your help is much appreciated!

Comment: `$(this).css('div#gold div.gold', 'gold');` ? Have you read the `.css()` documentation?

Comment: yer as I said I'm new to jquery I seen some examples however they only changed a background color or text color.

Comment: Need to reorganize your code... `var $this = $(this)` to cache the variable, easier to read and improve performance. And there is no element with class `.test` in the given DOM, so your code will never be executed

Comment: What *specific* element(s) do you need to change, and in what way?

Comment: ill update the jsfiddle and show what the box should be able to change to. http://jsfiddle.net/GHuwV/4/

Comment: That seems hideously complex; essentially (it *seems*) you want to change the `id`s of various elements to reflect the new colours. This can be done, but it's horrible. And far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I had a feeling this would be complex what would you recommend I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of hate this approach, it seems inherently overly-complex, but this *works* (though I almost wish it didn't):

```
// tying the selected option to the required colours:
var map = {
    'Each' : 'gold',
    'All' : 'gold',
    'Offer' : 'red',
    'Buying' : 'green'
},
// using the currently selected value to identify what string we're looking for in the id
    oldColour = map[$('#container select').val()];

$('select').change(function(){
    // caching variables, though it may not be needed
    var that = this,
        $that = $(that),
        container = $('#container'),
        colour = map[that.value];
    // finding all the elements whose id starts with the currently-selected colour
    container.find('[id^="' + oldColour + '"]').each(function(){
        // iterating over each of those elements, replacing the oldColour with the new colour
        this.id = this.id.replace(oldColour,colour);
    });
    // updating the oldColour variable for the next time
    oldColour = colour;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GHuwV/6/).

An improved approach to your code is the following, which relies upon changing a single class of the `#container` object, which relies on the updated HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="pricebox1">
        <div class="pricebox2">
            <input id="coin" type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="width: 35px; style=" height: 21px; maxlength=3 />
            <div class="selectbox1">
                <div class="selectbox2">
                    <div class="selectbox3">
                        <select name="qty">
                            <option value="Each" selected>Each</option>
                            <option value="All"> All</option>
                            <option value="Offer">Offer</option>
                            <option value="Buying">Buying</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pricebox3">
                <div class="pricebox4">
                    <div class="pricebox5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the incredibly simple jQuery:

```
var map = {
    'Each' : 'gold',
    'All' : 'gold',
    'Offer' : 'red',
    'Buying' : 'green'
};

// the following adds the class of the currently-selected colour to the #container
$('#container').addClass(map[$('#container select').val()]);

$('select').change(function(){
    var that = this;
    $('#container').attr('class', map[that.value]);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GHuwV/8/).

The CSS for the above has *also* been simplified:

```
/* styles the elements when the #container is .gold */
.gold .pricebox1,
.gold .pricebox2,
.gold .pricebox3,
.gold .pricebox4 {
    background-color: #EEC43A;
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
}
/* styles the elements when the #container is .green */
.green .pricebox1,
.green .pricebox2,
.green .pricebox3,
.green .pricebox4 {
    background-color: #0f0;
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
}
/* styles the elements when the #container is .red */
.red .pricebox1,
.red .pricebox2,
.red .pricebox3,
.red .pricebox4 {
    background-color: #f00;
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
}
/* base-styles that don't change */
.pricebox1 {
    background: none;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #361801;
    float:left;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.pricebox2 {
    background-color: #EEC43A;
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.pricebox3 {
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
}
.pricebox4 {
    border:1px solid #361801;
}
.pricebox5 {
    border:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background: white;
    width: 153px;
    min-height: 51px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom:25px;
}
.selectbox1 {
    border:1px solid #FDFF82;
}
.selectbox2 {
    border:1px solid #361801;
}
.selectbox3 {
    border:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: @undefined: thank you! I was going to leave the answer as it was originally written, and avoid the whole complexity problem; but any answer that starts with 'I kind of hate this...' really can't be finished without offering an improved alternative (and I really couldn't bring myself to edit-out the 'I kind of hate this...' part).

Answer (score 1):

You have made it very complex, instead of changing many IDs and classes and querying the DOM in an inefficient way, you can select a closest wrapper element and change it's class name, then using CSS inheritance you can easily style the descendant elements.

```
var colors = {
   Each: 'gold',
   All: 'gold',
   Offer: 'red',
   Buying: 'green'
} 

$('select.qty').change(function(){
   var cls = colors[this.value];
   $('#container').attr('class', cls);
});
```

Also note that `css` method is used for adding inline styles to the elements, you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: does this mean I have to change all me divs to a class instead of an id?

Comment: @KennenLasuni I don't know what exactly you mean by an ID, I can see many IDs and classes related to a single mode of styling, I would do this, plus changing IDs is not a good idea.

Comment: `id="example"` to `class="example"`. So how do I target the css that's labeled gold, red and green or don't I? I think I understand what its doing however would this require me to change the styling of each box? Would it be possible to effect a box with a hue? then I could have a default box and then have some way of changing its hue to get different box colors.

Comment: @KennenLasuni Well, you can select them using css selectors, `#container.green div { background-color: green }`, changing hues needs doing some math stuff or using a plugin which is again _complex_ approach for doing a simple task.